# WordPress plugin installation

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I am using the simple `add_filter` function to output the content.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_name');

function my_name( $content ){
  // code
  return $content;
}
```

When I activate the plug-in output of the function `my_name` is shown in all pages. How can I restrict the output to only one page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code and replace `yourpagename` with the your page slug on which u want this filter to execute

```
function my_name( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_name == 'yourpagename' ) {          
        return $content;
    } 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_name' );
```

Comment: I tried with 'about' for 'yourpagename', does not print any thing, how to enter this value?

Comment: `if ( $post->post_name == 'about' )` `about` should be slug of the page.

Comment: @naveenkumar Welcome

Comment: @naveenkumar If the answer works for you, please mark it as Accepted. (Just click the little checkmark on the left.)

Comment: @PatJ, use this reference: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667) ;)

Comment: @brasofilo -- Roger wilco. Bookmarked for future reference.